# How to find current snapped item in Lazy Column

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm using SnapFlingBehavior as described in

https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/gestures/snapping/SnapFlingBehavior

This API is provided as replacement of Chris Banes snapper library (https://github.com/chrisbanes/snapper)

In Snapper library we can get the current snapped position by doing

`snapperLayoutInfo.currentItem?.index`

How do get index of current snapped item using this new API.

Answer (score 0):

The `SnapFlingBehavior` itself knows no *current* item and is usually just provided to the `scrollable` modifier.
The composable that this `scrollable` modifier is applied to must understand the concept of a *current item*, if this is something that you need.

The compose framework provides out-of-the-box composables that handle all this internally, like the `Pager` and the `DatePicker`.

The more generic `LazyList` and `LazyGrid`, however, are scrollable (and therefore *snapflingable*), but they have no concept of a current item. What comes closest is the `firstVisibleItemIndex` property of the list's state. However, the first item of a list after a snap will often be only partially visible when using the default `SnapFlingBehavior` (which snaps to the center of the viewport). You could customize the SnapFlingBehavior to snap in a way that the firstVisibleItemIndex item is always *fully* visible. You would have to create your own `SnapLayoutInfoProvider` for this (possibly with the function `SnapLayoutInfoProvider(LazyListState, SnapPositionInLayout)`, so you just need to provide a customized `SnapPositionInLayout`).

If you use some other composable with a `SnapFlingBehavior` you have to make sure that this composable itself supports the concept of a *current item*.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```kotlin
    @Composable
    fun rememberSnapFlingSelectedIndex(listState: LazyListState) = remember {
        derivedStateOf {
            with(listState) {
                val itemsOnScreen = layoutInfo.visibleItemsInfo.size.takeIf { it != 0 } ?: 1

                when {
                    !canScrollBackward -> firstVisibleItemIndex
                    !canScrollForward -> firstVisibleItemIndex + itemsOnScreen - 1
                    else -> firstVisibleItemIndex + itemsOnScreen.div(2)
                    // Or you can write your own conditions to determine item position
                    // ...
                }
            }
        }

    }
```